# Let $\{Y_n\} =\{X_n\}^{1/n}$. Show that there is a constant $c$ such that $\{Y_n\}$ converges to $ c$ almost surely, and determine that $c$.

Tags: probability-theory

Especially for part b:
[image for the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/foPxw.png)

Answer (score 1):

Man, consider this new sequence:
$$S_n= \ln(X_n)$$
and,
$$T_n= S_n-S_{n-1} \forall n \ge 0$$
Under your assumptions,

- $T_n\underbrace{=}_{def.} \ln\left( \frac{X_n}{X_{n-1}}\right)$ is independent of $T_{n-1},T_{n-2},...,T_1$
- $S_n= T_n+T_{n-1}+...+T_1$
- And your term of interest $X_n^{1/n}$ is in fact $$\ln(X_n^{1/n})=\dfrac{T_n+T_{n-1}+...+T_1}{n}$$

Do you recall something now?

Comment: Thank you. So, according to the strong law of large number, then we can have ln(Xn^1/n) converges to E(Tn) a.s., then we can and should get our c here...

Comment: yeah, but I hope you do not forget to put some arguments to show that $(T_n,n \ge 1)$ are independent. That would make your solution perfect.